# Is there a way I could send a book primary key to a url in another django app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

**I want to make a book marketing web app using Django and I want to show the book details using another Django app, and I need the book primary key in the details app. my question is what is the best way to pass the book pk to the detail URL defined in the book_details app.**

this is my home urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_page_view, name='home'),
    path('books/', include('book_details.urls'), name='books'),
]
```

and this is my details app (book_details) urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import *

app_name = 'book_details'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', book_details_view, name="book_detail")
]
```

I tried doing it like this in the home app template and it does not work:

```
   <a href="{% url 'book_details:book_detail' post.pk %} " class="book-card-link">
```

the Error:

Reverse for 'book_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['books/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']

Sorry if my question is not very clear, it's my first time asking a question here, Thanks.

Comment: this error message tells that "post.pk" is empty. please show the view behind the template

Comment: the home template does get the books pk I tested it. it just won't pass the pk to the url because Im doing something wrong. thanks.

Comment: put xxx{% url 'book_details:book_detail' post.pk %}yyy somewhere in the html and post the result xxx....yyyy